# Removing a prepended array once code executed in Node.js

Tags: arrays, node.js, fs

I have an array called 'friends'  currently being passed into 'friendscalculator.js' held on my node server using the 'prependFile' module ( similar to fs.appendFile). However I'd like to remove the array content from 'friendscalculator.js' once the code in the calculator has been executed...

Any ideas on the best way to do this? I suppose a solution could be contained in the 'friendscalculator.js' file or in the node controller. Code:

controller.js

```
var friends = ["bob", "nick", "john"]

var fileVar = 'var friends = '+JSON.stringify(friends)+';';

prependFile('./likes.js', fileVar, function(err) {
res.writeHead(200, {
   "Content-Type": "text/javascript" });

   var readStream = fs.createReadStream("./friendscalculator.js")
      readStream.on('open', function() {
        readStream.pipe(res);
      });

      readStream.on('error', function(err) {
        res.end(err);
      })
    })
})
```

Comment: Why not just do res.write('var friends = ["bob", "nick", "john"]'); after your writeHead?  Don't use prependFile at all?

Comment: I didn't realize I could do that? How would I then remove this after the script has executed?

Comment: Also, would this method work for a dynamic variable?

Comment: Remove from where?  I think you are missing some code, but from what I understand, you are serving this file, correct?  This becomes dynamic, each time it is requested, you can pass whatever array you like.  To handle a changing array, just res.write('var friends = '+JSON.stringify(friends)+';')

Comment: I need to remove the passed dynamic variable from the 'friendscalculator.js' after it has executed. Otherwise i end up with 'var friends ='  being inserted each time, resulting in multiple 'var friend=' variables..

Comment: You need to describe what is happening better here.  Is a client requesting friendscalculator.js from your node server?  If so, my example never actually modifies friendscalculator.js, it just sends a dynamically created version each time requested.